# Show the object properties values using an object method

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object

I'm new to JS and I recently studied about objects and functions. Here I want to call a function for each object in an array of objects. I'm using `forEach` to do so. The result is `undefined` for each property.

```js
function showDetail() {
  console.log(`name: ${this.name}
         price: ${this.price}
         sold: ${this.sold}
         console: ${this.console}
         `);
}
const games = [{
    name: ' Crash Bandicoot N. Sane Trilogy',
    price: 1060,
    sold: 20,
    console: 'PS4',
  },
  {
    name: 'Lego Marvel Super Heroes',
    price: 700,
    sold: 25,
    console: 'XBOX',
    showDetail: function() {
      console.log(this.name);
    }
  },
  {
    name: 'Gta V',
    price: 1449,
    sold: 30,
    console: 'PS4',
    showDetail: function() {
      console.log(this.name);
    }
  }
];
games.forEach(showDetail);
```

The result is like this for each object:

```
name: undefined
     price: undefined
     sold: undefined
     console: [object Object]
 games.forEach(showDetail);
```

Comment: To bind the game as context, you can do `games.forEach(i => { showDetail.bind(i)() });`

Comment: @ChrisG: There's no reason to use `.bind()` like that. If you're calling the function immediately, you use `.call` or `.apply` to set the value of the *thisArg*. `games.forEach(obj => showDetail.call(obj));`

Answer (score 3):

You should pass a 'game' as parameter to the function and print its properties, not from 'this'

```
function showDetail(game){
   console.log(`name: ${game.name}
   price: ${game.price}
   sold: ${game.sold}`);
}

const games = [ ..... ]
games.forEach( function(game) { showDetail(game) });
//if there is support for arrow functions, it's cleaner
games.forEach( game => showDetail(game) );
//also, as mentioned by Máté in the comments
games.forEach( showDetail ); //will work
```

If you want the 'showDetail' function to work with this 'this', you should bind the 'game' to the function

```
games.forEach( game => showDetail.bind(game)() );
function showDetail(){
   //here the 'this' is the 'game', because it has been bounded via .bind() method
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: `games.forEach( function(game) { showDetail(game) });` is overkill. `games.forEach(showDetail);` works just fine, since `showDetail()` will receive the `game` as a parameter. In this case at least, when the argument can be passed as-is.

Comment: Thanks @MátéSafranka I'm not used to this approach, I usually expose the parameters. I didn't remeber this way you mentioned will work. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Yeah I edited my comment a bit to clarify as well. It's more common that we need to transform the arguments in some way before passing them to the callback, so it doesn't hurt if OP sees that option too.

Comment: @MátéSafranka Thank you. Why is `this` not working? `Foreach` is iterating through the array of objects and the function should know that it's an object.

Comment: Because the function isn't being invoked as a method of the object. You're probably confusing it with event handlers.

Comment: @Hanna: Upon what are you basing your idea of what "should" happen?

Comment: I have updated my answer, explaining how you can use the 'this' keyworn inside the function, with it being a reference to the 'game' variable, via .bind() method

Comment: `games.forEach( game => showDetail.bind(game) );` Your use of `.bind()` is incorrect.

Comment: @CrazyTrain I have just fixed it, it was missing the invocation, with ()

Comment: OK, now it's *technically* correct but just not good. There's no need to create a new function on every iteration just to set its `this` value.

Comment: @CrazyTrain I know. That's why I have not added this in my first reply. I just added this option, using bind, so the OP can understand how to bind the variable to the target function's 'this'

Comment: No, I mean wouldn't use `.bind()` at all. You can do your last solution without having to generate a new function using `.bind()` on every iteration. See @Shubham Khatri's answer to learn how to do it properly.

Answer (score 2):

When you write

```
games.forEach(showDetail);
```

showDetails is a callback function of forEach and it is passed the object as the first parameter and hence you would write

```
function showDetail(game) {
  console.log(`name: ${game.name}
         price: ${game.price}
         sold: ${game.sold}
         console: ${game.console}
         `);
}
```

when you `this` inside showDetail, the this value is `not binded` to the object context and hence `this.name` doesn't return the object value. However if you write

```
games.forEach(game => {
   showDetail.call(game);
});
```

you are providing the context to be object and this case `this.name` inside showDetail will work

Comment: @ChrisG, well I did add more details on why OP code was not giving the desired output

Comment: @ChrisG: This answer gives more information. Which answer is "first" is irrelevant.

Comment: @CrazyTrain I'm aware of that, thanks. I posted before he edited his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean this

```js
// constructor

function Game(parms) {
  this.name = parms.name;
  this.price = parms.price;
  this.sold = parms.sold;
  this.gconsole = parms.gconsole;
}

// toString override

Game.prototype.toString = function() {
  return `name: ${this.name}
         price: ${this.price}
         sold: ${this.sold}
         gconsole: ${this.gconsole}
         `;
}

const games = [
  new Game({
    name: ' Crash Bandicoot N. Sane Trilogy',
    price: 1060,
    sold: 20,
    gconsole: 'PS4'
  }),
  new Game({
    name: 'Lego Marvel Super Heroes',
    price: 700,
    sold: 25,
    gconsole: 'XBOX'
  }),
  new Game({
    name: 'Gta V',
    price: 1449,
    sold: 30,
    gconsole: 'PS4'
  })
];
games.forEach(function(g) {
  console.log(g.toString());
});
```